# How do I solve the subgrouping in nested gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview problem while binding more than two gridviews.

I am giving a sample scenario of what I have done so far

I have two tables

First table: Department , having columns DeptId and DeptName

10    Accounts
20    Software

Second Table: Emp having columns EmpId, EmpName,Salary,
DeptID.

101    aaa    100    10
101    aaa    200    10
101    aaa    300    10
202    bb    101    20
202    bb    102    20
102    cc    100    10
201    dd    103    20

I am supposed to show first all the employees ordered by their deptname.

Also I am supposed to show the sum of each employees salary and sum of the entire department's salary

So the above values should appear as below

101    aaa    100    10
101    aaa    200    10
101    aaa    300    10
sum of emp 101 is  600
102    cc    100    10
sum of emp 102 is  100
SUM OF DEPT 10 IS 700

202    bb    101    20
202    bb    102    20
sum of emp 202 is  203
201    dd    103    20
sum of emp 202 is  103
SUM OF DEPT 20 IS 306

I am able to fetch sum of dept salary but not of employees

I have tried as below

My Design Page

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptID" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpId" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView3"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SumSalary" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My CodeBehind Page

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
      SqlConnection MyCon=new SqlConnection("server=ABC-415D0247602\\SQLEXPRESS; database=Employee ;integrated security=true;connection timeout=600");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter MyDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from department", MyCon);
        DataSet MyDs = new DataSet();
        MyDa.Fill(MyDs);
        DataTable MyDt = new DataTable();
        GridView1.DataSource = MyDs.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string j = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

            GridView GridView2 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2");
            SqlDataAdapter MyDa1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Emp where deptid =" +Convert.ToInt16(j), MyCon);
            DataSet MyDs1 = new DataSet();
            MyDa1.Fill(MyDs1);
            DataTable MyDt1 = new DataTable();
            GridView2.DataSource = MyDs1.Tables[0];
            GridView2.DataBind();

            GridView GridView3 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView3");
            SqlDataAdapter MyDa2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select sum(salary) as SumSalary from Emp where deptid =" + Convert.ToInt16(j), MyCon);
            DataSet MyDs2 = new DataSet();
            MyDa2.Fill(MyDs2);
            DataTable MyDt2 = new DataTable();
            GridView3.DataSource = MyDs2.Tables[0];
            GridView3.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know where to place the sum of the employee's salary

Thanks in advance
Regards
cmrhema

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier, using repeaters :)
however because of the challange i did the following:

```
 //Here lays the dragons
```

A small note: 1st you dont need  3 gridViews to order by depid , you can use :

```
 SELECT * FROM Emp  Order By depid
```

this can Combine both GridwView1 and GridView2, and to design it, just combine the columns from Gridview1 and 2 like Shown in the solution below.

The design of GridView1

```
 < asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptID" /> 
             <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" />
            </Columns>
```

**Solution:**

**WARNING : This Solution is not simple,and definetly not optimized :)**

The idea is to do the manipulation before binding the data to the GridViews.

The solution If your using 2 GridViews (like i recommended above)
on page_load, run the above SQL, and fill it in a Dataset (DS1), 
Create a table (dt) with the data u filled in DS1
Then create a clone DataTable (dt2)

then start a loop through the rows of dt1 
1st you record the EmpID as CurrentID 
loop (foreach row in dt1) throughRowDataBound the rows summing the salary from each row untill CurrentID != ReadID
Add a row to the Dataset(DS1) with column "EMPID"'s value = "-54321"  //this will be used later to identify the irregular rows//
, and the salary = Sum 
make the sum = 0,
Make CurrentID = ReadID Continue the loop;

then Bind DS1 To gridView1.

ON Event: GridView1_RowCreated

you check if the Row being Created has the ID "-54321" (using DataRowView) if it does , u Read the sum into a variable, then Clear , add columns as desired, something like :

```
           e.Row.Cells.Clear(); 
            TableCell oCell = new TableCell(); 
            e.Row.Cells.Add(oCell);
```

A similar approach can be used to add the extra row for the Dep salary sum :)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly I am not going to downvote the answer.
You suggested repeaters, but I went for datalist control instead of the parent grid. Actually I am going for 7 different tables and doing inner join in LINQ TO SQL and thereby retrieving the answer in Ilist.
As I was not able to frame all the 7 tables and stuff, I just provided a small snapshot of the whole page.

Here's what I did
Took a datalist had the keynames as deptid. (1st datalist)
Took another datalist (datalist2) in the item template of datalist1, bearing the keynames of empid
Dropped a gridview in the datalist2, which will have the employee details in the template field of gridview, and had a footer row .

Now the pseudo code was something nearer to this

for i =1 to datalist1
bind datalist2
for j=1 to datalist2
bind gridview

in the rowdatabound of gridview
{
sum up the salaries

if (datarow==footerrow)
{
   display the footer along with the summed up salaries
}

Thanks
Regards
cmrhema